# Jquery does not work when I request to rest service (spring boot)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, spring-boot

I'm working on a spring boot rest api and I want to take information from rest api to a html page. I tried this using jquery but I could not take data.

Here is my Rest Controller

```
package tr.kasim.Controller;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import tr.kasim.Service.PersonelService;
import tr.kasim.Service.PtsGirisCikisService;
import tr.kasim.Model.Personel;
import tr.kasim.Model.PtsGiriscikis;

@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
public class STRestController {

@Autowired
public PersonelService personelService;

@Autowired
public PtsGirisCikisService ptsGirisCikisService;

@GetMapping("/api/personels")
public ResponseEntity<List<Personel>> getPersonels(){
    List<Personel> personels = personelService.findAll();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(personels);
}

@GetMapping("/api/giriscikis")
public ResponseEntity<List<PtsGiriscikis>> getGirisCikis(){
    List<PtsGiriscikis> giriscikis = ptsGirisCikisService.findAll();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(giriscikis);
}

//@GetMapping("/api/personel")
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/api/personel", produces="application/json" )
public ResponseEntity<List<PtsGiriscikis>> getPersonelByKartNoAndİseGiris(@RequestParam("kartno") String KartNo , @RequestParam("tarih") Date IseGirisTarihi){
    String errorMessage="Aranilan Personel Bulunamadi!";

    Personel personel = personelService.findPersonelByKartnoAndIsegiristarihi(KartNo , IseGirisTarihi);

    if(!personel.equals(null)) {
        List<PtsGiriscikis> girisCikis = ptsGirisCikisService.findByPersonelid(personel.getId());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(girisCikis);
    }

        return null;
}

}
```

Here is my Controller

```
package tr.kasim.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class STController {

@GetMapping("/")
public String goHome() {
    return "templates/index";
}
}
```

Here is index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function findPersonels() {
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "/api/personels",
                contentType: "application/json"
            }).then(function(data) {
                $('.giriscikis-id').append(data.id);
                $('.giriscikis-ad').append(data.ad);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>

        <p class="giriscikis-id">The ID is </p>
        <p class="giriscikis-ad">The name is </p>
        <input type="button" id="doldur" name="doldur" value="field doldur" onclick="findPersonels();">
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried many jquery + spring application examples but I still got nothing. When I tried to reach index.html I just saw my html writings, rest service information are not showing. Please correct me, thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed error information? Did you click the button? I am sure your browsers console does contain some error.

Comment: Hello, when I try to reach default context("localhost:8080") I took that error : Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Apr 29 11:32:45 EET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available 
 But, when I try to reach "localhost:8080/templates/index.html" I can see my page without rest service informations.

Comment: Your `http404` is a different problem. You defined `onclick="findPersonels();"` so only when you click on the button your AJAX call will be executed. What is the output in the error console of your browser **after** you click the button?

Comment: Oke, here is the console error: `index.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: findPersonels is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:14)
onclick @ index.html:14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the limited information:

1. I guess your mapping from path to template is wrong. Shouldn't it be like this?

   @GetMapping("/")
   public String goHome() {
       return "templates/index";
   }
2. An `Uncaught ReferenceError` indicates that your method is not found. Please verify the spelling (looks fine in your example, please check again in your code). In your example the braces of findPersonels are totally messed up. There is too many `)`. If that is corrected check in your browser console that there is no `http404` when loading the page (so that `js/personels.js` is found).
3. Your endpoint `/api/personels` defines a list as return type but your script uses the properties `data.ad` and `data.id` which do not look like they expect a list. The returned json probably looks something like this `{ items: [ { 'ad': 'first personel' 'id': '1' }, { 'ad': 'second personel' 'id': '2' } ] }` The structure depends on your JSON marshaller. So a correct syntax for accessing 
   your object in JS would be somehting like `data.items[0].id`.

Comment: Hello again, I checked my function and you are right, there was syntax error. I correct it but now Im clicking to function, and I took no error and no output.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please try to verify your work yourself by checking in little steps. For example open `localhost:8080//api/personels` and see what the output is. Does it match to what you expect in `function findPersonels() {`? Not only expect things to be correct; **verify**.

Comment: Hello, I updated question, too. Firstly, when I reached `/api/personels` I got a personel list with person information. That personel info have 'id' and 'ad' fields. I want to pull them to html page. After correcting function syntax, I should work but still I got nothing.

Comment: I think you need to add application name as well in the url i.e before `/api/personels` ;

Comment: I check console-network , when I click function, it can get api/personel data but it could not parsing it to my html page. I need help at this point now.

Comment: I updated the answer. I already pointed out your return type is not a single object but a list. This is easily observable in network console. If you disagree please post what your JSON looks like.